# How does that casting work?

Tags: c++

I'm doing an exercise for my uni class. I've stumbled upon a following line of code:

```
std::cout << (const MaszynaStanow&)m << std::endl;
```

*where m is an object of a class.*

It doesn't compile. I assume it's some kind of a casting of an object to a constant reference, right?

I've also written an operator function for "<<" overloading so that I could print out the values held by an object like so:

```
std::cout << m;
```

I'm getting the following error upon compilation:

```
.main.cpp:41:13: error: invalid operands to binary expression('ostream'(aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'const MaszynaStanow')
std::cout << (const MaszynaStanow&)m << std::endl;
~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Which makes me think that my operator overloading function is not suitable in this case(?)

```
ostream & operator<<(ostream & stream, MaszynaStanow & obj){
    cout<<"MaszynaStanow:"<<endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < obj.size; ++i){
        stream <<i<<" "<<obj.Next[i]->returnName();
        if (i == obj.chosenMode) cout <<" <";
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return stream;
}
```

I would appreciate any kind of help- even a small hint.

Comment: Look at *`const`*, or at the missing one.

Comment: your `ostream::operator<<` pretends that it modifies the passed `MaszynaStanow` thus it rejects a `const` instance. Btw the question is rather unclear, because if you simply remove the cast the error should be gone

Comment: @OlafDietsche I knew it must have been something stupidly obvious. Thank you very much- spotted the error straight away!!

Comment: @user463035818, I know but the way our programming classes are being handled is that we are being given only a main.cpp file with already written code. We have to make it compile by adding .h and .cpp files. We are not allowed to edit the main.cpp file, therefore I couldn't have deleted that line of code.

Comment: @Mike.e87 yes, got it, just took me a while to understand that it isnt your code. The code you are given isnt nice at all btw, but maybe thats part of the exercise

Comment: @user463035818 exactly, that's the point. I hate that approach but there's nothing I can really do about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cast explicitly to a `const`, but your operator is only able to work with non-const instances of `MaszynaStanow`. Your operator should have the following form:

```
ostream & operator<<(ostream & stream, const MaszynaStanow & obj)
                                       ^^^^^
                                       you missed this
```

If you need the object to be modifiable, keep the current version and do not cast the object to a const one. Although I would not expect `operator<<` to modify its right-handled operand, so the const should be probably there.

Comment: Totally agreed. I just missed it... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the programmer is trying to simulate a pass-by-const-reference by doing a previous cast to the object. However, the true place to do any modification is here:

```
ostream & operator<<(ostream & stream, MaszynaStanow & obj){
    cout<<"MaszynaStanow:"<<endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < obj.size; ++i){
        stream <<i<<" "<<obj.Next[i]->returnName();
        if (i == obj.chosenMode) cout <<" <";
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return stream;
}
```

While you are going to dump *obj* to the stream *stream*, which presumably does not require any modification of *obj*, you are passing a non-constant reference. Fix the code this way:

```
ostream & operator<<(ostream & stream, const MaszynaStanow & obj){
    cout<<"MaszynaStanow:"<<endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < obj.size; ++i){
        stream <<i<<" "<<obj.Next[i]->returnName();
        if (i == obj.chosenMode) cout <<" <";
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return stream;
}
```

Now you are passing *obj* by reference, but this reference is special: while it s very efficient, it is equivalent (because of the use of `const`) to a pass-by-value.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! it did help me out. I must have missed this const when copying the first line of the function from a different file...